# Estou tendo um erro em meu exercício em c++. O que eu posso fazer para consertar?

Tags: c++

```
#include <math.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float R;
    float pi = 3.14159;
    float volume = (4.0 / 3) * pi * pow(R, 3);
    cin >> R;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3);
    cout << "VOLUME = " << volume << endl;
}
```

E Essa é a minha saída.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez você devesse fazer a leitura da variável `R` **antes** de utiliza-la nos cálculos.

Answer (score 1):

A entrada `R` é requisitada **depois** de ser usada no cálculo. É preciso alterar o código para algo como

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float R;
    float pi = 3.14159;
    float volume;

    cin >> R;
    volume = (4.0 / 3) * pi * pow(R, 3);

    cout << fixed << setprecision(3);
    cout << "VOLUME = " << volume << endl;
}
```